# How to make existing table column value unique in vertica which are duplicate?

Tags: vertica

I have a vertica table "Product" it contains product_id, order_id and some more columns. order_id is a varchar column.

it has data like this:

```
product_id   order_id
1               a:111
2               a:222
3               a:111
2               a:444
1               a:222
4               a:111
```

now i want to update order_id each row which are duplicate(want to make unique). like this:

```
product_id   order_id
1               a:112
2               a:222
3               a:113
2               a:444
1               a:223
4               a:114
```

how to do this?

Comment: Also, please take time to go through `https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask`

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure if updating would be the right idea for vertica.
However, you can use the below select statement.

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT product_id
    -- , order_id
    , order_id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY product_id
        , rank ORDER BY order_id
        ) AS as order_id
FROM (
    SELECT product_id
        , order_id
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY order_id
            ) AS rank
    FROM abc
    ) sub;
```

Let us know if this works for you.

Comment: I am getting this error while executing this query:   Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [4856] [42601]: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near "order_id"